# Paint polygon already drawn

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm trying make a volume user control (only the UI). I have everything working, except when the bar goes below 50% of picturebox.Width (which is 100) I want the triangle colour to change, for example from red to green. The three lines commented in mouseMove event is what I want to accomplish, but that won't work. Thank you in advance.

This is an example of my control:

[image]

My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;

namespace ControlAudio
{
    public partial class volumen: UserControl
    {
        Bitmap im_soundOn = Properties.Resources.sound_on;
        Bitmap im_soundOff = Properties.Resources.sound_off;
        int coordenadaX;
        bool barClicked = false;
        bool muted = false;

        public volumen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        //Dibujar triangulo
        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var g = e.Graphics;
            var points = new PointF[] { new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(1, 0), new PointF(0, 1) };

            var mx = g.Transform.Clone();

            g.TranslateTransform(100f, 100f);
            g.ScaleTransform(-135f, -70f);
            g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Olive, points);
            g.Transform = mx;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            barClicked = true;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            barClicked = false;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
            Point coordenadasNuevas = me.Location;
            coordenadaX = coordenadasNuevas.X;

            if(barClicked && pictureBox1.Width <= 100)
            {
                if (coordenadaX > 100)
                {
                    coordenadaX = 100;
                }
                pictureBox1.Width = coordenadaX;
            }

            //When it reaches 0
            if (pictureBox1.Width == 0) {
                pictureBox1.Width = 0;
                muted = true;
                pb_imagen.Image = im_soundOff;
            }
            else //When it goes over 0
            {
                muted = false;
                pb_imagen.Image = im_soundOn;
            }

            //if(pictureBox1.Width <= 50) g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Olive, points);
            //if(pictureBox1.Width >50 && pictureBox1.Width <= 90) g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Yellow, points);
            //if (pictureBox1.Width > 90) g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Red, points);

        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Store the information you need for the paint event and just call `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` from the MouseMove method.  In the paint event, use the information you stored to determine your points or colors since that is where you are painting stuff.

Comment: Sorry my ignorance but I'm new to C# and I don't know how this polygon painting works, I just know it works and that modifying some values I can use it. But I don't know how it's made. I get the call to Invalidate(); but I don't know how to do the rest of it.

Comment: In your paint event, you are using Brushes.Olive.  If you want a different color based on some information in the MouseMove event, you will need a variable at the form level.  Set that variable to the brush color you want to use.  Use that brush in your FillPolygon to use the color you want.

Comment: Now I got it and I did it. It wasn't very complicated, I was thinking in a harder way :/ Thank you so much Lars!! :)

Comment: Put answers in the answer box below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this, and thanks to @LarsTech, I did the following:

1. Created a brush with the default colour: `Brush brush = Brushes.Red;`
2. In the `pictureBox1_Paint` event I changed the previous `g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Olive, points);` to `g.FillPolygon(brush, points);`
3. In the `MouseMove` event, I added the following:

   ```
   if (pictureBox1.Width <= 50)
   {
       brush = Brushes.LightGreen;
       pictureBox1.Invalidate();
   }
   else if (pictureBox1.Width > 50 && pictureBox1.Width <= 90)
   {
       brush = Brushes.Yellow;
       pictureBox1.Invalidate();
   }
   else
   {
       brush = Brushes.Red;
       pictureBox1.Invalidate();
   }
   ```